# How to create a regular expression for the following matches

Tags: regex

I'm currently trying to come up with a regular expression that matches the following chunks.

A few examples:

```
07280969963593626387L
113843230015664032748F
```

In other words, I'm looking for any string which contains 20 or 21 digits and ending with a capital letter.

Comment: I doubt this is what you want, but here you go :) `07280969963593626387L` - take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: Okay, after your edit: `(07280969963593626387L|113843230015664032748F)`. You haven't specified your pattern clearly enough, and once you do, the linked duplicates should become helpful.

Comment: Thanks , I just show 2 examples for the string . I found some regex :^\d{21}[A-Z]$,is it right or not?

Comment: @Packy, _we **don't know**_. You need to _clearly define what should match, and what should not_. Are you looking for any string that contains 21 digits and then a capital letter? You haven't said that anywhere. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Nikita Fedyashev thanks

Comment: @Chris yes,I'm looking for any string which contains 20 or 21 digits and ending with a capital letter

Comment: Then you need to _say that in your question_. Where did the 20 digits come from? Your proposed regex specifies 21. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris finally,I got it ,[0-9]{20,21}[A-Z],Thanks